# mark specific dataset in filtered grid

Tags: select, filter, grid, axapta

i'm just struggling through the following situation -
there's a datasource added to a grid in axapta 2009, filtered by a querybuildrange.

i want to mark a specific dataset by x++ via

```
datasource_DS.findrecord( specificRecord )
```

this works as intended, removing the filter, but not having the filter active!
a workaround to remove the filter and add everything ( filtered! )to a temporary table first is not what i want.

i can't imagine there's no way to achieve this task?!
thanks in advance!

edit:

datasources on form:
 - ProdRouteJob ( JoinSource: ProdTable, LinkType: InnerJoin )
 - ProdTable

only datasets containing a specified ProdStatus should be displayed in the grid.
This is done by the mentioned Range, e.g.:

```
prodStatusRange =  prodTable_ds.query().dataSourceTable( tablenum( ProdTable )).addRange( fieldnum( ProdTable, ProdStatus ));
prodStatusRange.value( "(( ProdStatus == 0) || ( ProdStatus == 1 ))" );
```

*selecting* a specified dataset is done by, e.g.:

```
ProdRouteJob currentProdRouteJob;
;
currentProdRouteJob = ProdRouteJob::findJobId( "JOB_12345" );
info ( currentProdRouteJob.JobId );
prodRouteJob_DS.findRecord( currentProdRouteJob );
```

the info-function shows the correct JobId.
if i remove the filter, `findRecord()` *selects* the dataset, if not - not.
adding the `DS.research( true );` does not change this behaviour.

Comment: The following is not quite clear: "this works as intended, removing the filter, but not having the filter active".

State your intention.

Comment: `findRecord` does not "mark a specific dataset", it selects a specific record as the active one.

Comment: comment to first statement: if i run the code, after removing the filtering - the dataset _selects_ the specific dataset in the grid. if the filter is active, the selection of the specified dataset doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

You objective is to redraw the grid and to retain any filtering.

In AX 2009 it is easy:

```
datasource_DS.research(true);
```

In AX 4.0 and previous you can research and then refind:

```
specificRecord = datasource.data();
datasource_DS.research();
datasource_DS.findRecord(specificRecord)
```

This can sometimes be slow if there are many records in the grid.

Comment: whether i'm using your suggested code or not, the behaviour is the same. the specified dataset is not selected. maybe, there's a mistake at my side. i'll post the code below.

Comment: Try to simplify your range expression as: `prodStatusRange.value("0,1");`

Also after the change of the range a `ds.executeQuery()` must run.

A `ds.executeQuery()` or `ds.research()` must precede the `findRecord` for it to be effective.